# ENVI5.0. Is it possible to use "Quickmap" option? How to create a simple map?

Tags: envi

I used to work in ENVI 4.8, but now have to move on ENVI5.0 
I found it was changed a lot comparably with the previous versions, obtained  many good new options, but some old options, in ENVI4.8, are disappeared or so significantly changed, that it’s not easy to find them quickly.

ENVI4.8 has a good simple option to create map from a scene rapidly – “Quickmap” (File > QuickMap > New QuickMap)
I can’t find this option in ENVI 5.
I can’t find any possibility to create map here (with legend, title, etc).
How is it possible to create a simple map in ENVI5?
Or, what option substitutes “Quickmap”?

Answer (score 1):

To make your operation of QuickMap with ENVI5, you need to open the ENVI5 classic, after that open the viewer data, in the bare menu you find the option QuickMap.
You can see in the image attached.
[image]Good luck, 
Soufiane